# How to tell a public function to reference the name of the new object that called it?

Tags: vb.net

This is on my class form:

```
Public Class mailmessage

    Property msgsubject As String
    Property msgto As String
    Property msgfrom As String
    Property msgbody As String
    Property msgcc As String

    public function sendMsg()


    end function

end class
```

this is in my userform:

```
Sub reassign()
    Dim assignmsg As New mailmessage

    With assignmsg
        .msgsubject = "A new task has been assigned to you."
        .msgfrom = Environment.UserName & "@" & companyDomain.text & ".com"
        .msgbody = Textbox5.text
        .msgto = mailRecipent.text
    End With

    assignmsg.sendMsg()

    End Sub
```

I am assuming I set it up properly so that assignmsg.sendMsg will activate the sendMsg function on behalf of "assignmsg".

My question is, say I want the sendMsg function to do the following:

```
dim emailreceiver as string

emailreceiver = '(the new object I created that called the function, in this case it is "assignmsg").msgto
```

How would I tell it to convert the variable from the assignMsg object I created (assignmsg.msgto) to the string within the function?

Comment: I cannot figure out what you are trying to ask.  What type is `emailto`?  Wouldnt it be a string?  how is it different than `.msgto`?

Comment: sorry, it was emailreceiver not emailto. I corrected the typo. What I am trying to figure out is how to have the public function make the variable "emailreceiver" = the msgTo property of the object that called it

Comment: Your `mailmessage` Type does not have a Name property, so either you are out of luck unless you add one, or I still dont understand what you want.  ("assignmsg" is not a name!  it is an object reference (variable) in your code.  there is a difference)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure either then, I'm very new to OOP. Basically I was trying to create a sendMsg function that will send out an e-mail, and populate its fields based on properties from an object.

The idea would be that there were different types of "canned" email messages that would be sent, yet each type of canned message would have the same fields, so I was trying to assign them properties so that new types of e-mails to be sent could be created as objects, and then just told to "send"

Comment: But "assignmsg" is not a property, it is an object variable in your code

Comment: You have an instance of `mailmessage` (the reference to it is is in the variable `assignmsg`). For *that* instance, you have set various properties. Those properties will be available to methods of the `mailmessage` class. So in your `sendMsg` function, you simply use the properties as normal variables. Each instance of `mailmessage` will have its own set of those properties.

Comment: Yes, appears I do not understand the concept of objects. Does my end result make sense? I was trying to streamline sending different types of emails.

Comment: you are not going to be able to email an object, so no, it makes little sense.  I. still confused by the instance object calling the emailer function also being the receiver.

Comment: Andrew, how would I code sendMsg so that it pulls the properties from the instance of "mailmessage" and converts them to variables it can use?

Comment: Well if you were going to code something where many types of e-mails could be sent, and you wanted a way to have a new sub quickly specify the from, to, subject, and body of an e-mail and then send it (without having to re-type the entire email send function each time), what process would you use? This was my best guess as I begin to learn OOP.

Comment: @user5480156 You don't need to do anything, Just use them. N.B. The name "mailmessage" for your class is a Bad Choice because it conflicts with the MailMesage class in the .NET framework.

Comment: `how would I code sendMsg so that it pulls the properties from...` you are already doing that in the `With` block.  You probably just need another property or two (or a param to that method) for this missing piece

Comment: @Andrew Morton, my question was how to reference them. I do not know how to have the function to have 'variable = .msgto property value of object that called it'


Edit: I think I figured it out, I just did MsgBox(msgto) and it worked. I am assuming that by calling the property (msgto) it just pulls the last object that used it's property value?

Comment: @user5480156 You can think of an instance (which you make with `New`) of a class as having its very own set of data (say, the properties). When you call a method (Sub or Function) *on that instance* then the properties of that instance are used in the method. P.S. You *really* need to change the name of your class to something other than "mailmessage" or you will find things go wrong. Also, I recommend that you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the tips, I got it working as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, here is a suggestion based on one variation one the question: how do I pass some context information to the new object.

Invoke it via:

```
    Dim mm As New mailmessage(mailmessage.etype.Hello)
    mm.msgbody = "Hello World"
    'mm.  .... 
    mm.sendMsg()

Public Class mailmessage
Enum etype
    Hello
    GoodBy
    StilInterested
End Enum
Private _type As etype = Nothing

Property msgsubject As String
Property msgto As String
Property msgfrom As String
Property msgbody As String
Property msgcc As String

Public Sub sendMsg()
    Select Case _type
        Case etype.Hello
            '... log hello message
        Case Else
            '...
    End Select
    ' send
End Sub
Sub New(Optional MailType As etype = Nothing)
    _type = MailType
End Sub
End Class
```